# Disable selection of previous hours in the list using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Assume the time is 16:18, I want to disable the previous hour selections, like this: https://i.hizliresim.com/k3l0taj.png

I just need to check the previous hours if only the hours of today are trying to be selected. I mean if you are trying to select a time interval for tomorrow or some other days later then all options can be selected, like this: https://i.hizliresim.com/qf2es65.png

My code:

```
.col-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-6.col-xl-6
              h3.mb-2.mt-2 Saat Seç
              .meet-btn-area
                el-button.mb-2.mr-2(
                  v-for="item in times",
                  :key="item.value",
                  size="medium",
                  :type="item.value == time.value ? 'info' : ''",
                  :active="item.value == time",
                  @click="time = item"
                ) {{ item.text }}

times: [
        {
          value: "09:00",
          text: "09:00 - 09:30",
        },
        {
          value: "09:30",
          text: "09:30 - 10:00",
        },
        {
          value: "10:00",
          text: "10:00 - 10:30",
        },
        {
          value: "10:30",
          text: "10:30 - 11:00",
        },
        {
          value: "11:00",
          text: "11:00 - 11:30",
        },
        {
          value: "11:30",
          text: "11:30 - 12:00",
        },
        {
          value: "12:00",
          text: "12:00 - 12:30",
        },
        {
          value: "12:30",
          text: "12:30 - 13:00",
        },
        {
          value: "13:00",
          text: "13:00 - 13:30",
        },
        {
          value: "13:30",
          text: "13:30 - 14:00",
        },
        {
          value: "14:00",
          text: "14:00 - 14:30",
        },
        {
          value: "14:30",
          text: "14:30 - 15:00",
        },
        {
          value: "15:00",
          text: "15:00 - 15:30",
        },
        {
          value: "15:30",
          text: "15:30 - 16:00",
        },
        {
          value: "16:00",
          text: "16:00 - 16:30",
        },
        {
          value: "16:30",
          text: "16:30 - 17:00",
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:
[Demo: Vue items according to current time on Codepen](https://codepen.io/josfabre/pen/ZEJjqRb)

You can create a class bases on item properties:

```
// time for comparison

const now = new Date();


// component

<div id="app">
    <button v-for="item in times" :key="item.value" :class="cls(item)">{{ item.text }}</button>
</div>

// methods prop in Vue app

... 
methods: {
    cls: (item) => {
        const timeSplit = item.value.split(":");
        const itemDate = new Date();
        itemDate.setHours(timeSplit[0], timeSplit[1]);
        return itemDate > now ? "active" : "";
    }
}
...
```